# Frame and Canvas grow larger than specified

Tags: java, jframe, awt, jpanel

I have no idea why I am getting an extra-large window, this is making me run hoops to fit my sprites in the game-window. The constructor should make it so all the subcomponents fit into eachother, but it seems like there is some extra padding in the canvas or frame. I am having a tough time figuring out what the culprit is. The size of my frame should NOT be larger than 800x600 (OS decoration not included, talking about the containers).

```
Panel: java.awt.Rectangle[x=0,y=0,width=810,height=610]
Frame: java.awt.Rectangle[x=0,y=0,width=816,height=638]
Canvas:java.awt.Rectangle[x=0,y=0,width=816,height=638]
```

As you can see the bounds are larger than I specifed.

The class:

```
public class GameFrame {
private JFrame frame;
private JPanel panel;
private Canvas canvas;
private BufferStrategy bufferStrategy;
private Graphics2D g;
private int width;
private int height;

public GameFrame(Color bgColor) {
    this.width = GameEngine.GAMEDIMENSION[0]; // 800
    this.height = GameEngine.GAMEDIMENSION[1]; // 600
    this.frame = new JFrame();
    this.panel = (JPanel) frame.getContentPane();
    this.panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    this.panel.setLayout(null);
    this.panel.setBackground(bgColor);
    this.canvas = new Canvas();
    this.canvas.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);
    this.canvas.setIgnoreRepaint(true);
    this.frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    this.frame.pack();
    this.frame.setResizable(false);
    this.frame.setVisible(true);
    this.panel.add(canvas);
    this.canvas.createBufferStrategy(2);
    this.bufferStrategy = canvas.getBufferStrategy();
    this.g = (Graphics2D) bufferStrategy.getDrawGraphics();
    this.canvas.requestFocus();

}
```

The main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    GameFrame gf = new GameFrame(Color.black);
    System.out.println("Panel: " + gf.panel.getBounds());
    System.out.println("Frame: " + gf.frame.getBounds());
    System.out.println("Canvas:" + gf.frame.getBounds());

    for (int R = 0; R < 255; R++) {
        for (int B = 0; B < 255; B++) {
            for (int G = 0; G < 255; G++) {
                gf.g.setColor(Color.black);
                gf.g.fillRect(0, 0, gf.width, gf.height);
                gf.g.setColor(new Color(R, B, G));
                gf.g.fillRect(0, 0, gf.width, gf.height);
                gf.bufferStrategy.show();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

In the main I try to loop squares just to see the effect.
[image]

Comment: 1- I'd recommend against using a `null` layout. 2- Try swapping the `setResiable` and `setVisible` statements, so that the frame is visible first

Comment: Just to add on to that, do `setLocationByPlateform(true)` so that you can see the frame better.

Comment: Why are you playing with a BufferStrategy? That is a strategy for AWT. Swing is double buffered.

Comment: I am a bit paranoid when it comes to that, I am making sure I do have buffering enabled in my game. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: @syb0rg You could also use `frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);` to center it one the screen ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer To me, a GUI in the middle of the screen looks "splash-screenish". Just a matter of preference :P

Comment: @camickr The only reason I can think for using double buffering in this manner is the difference active and passive rendering (Swing been passive)

Comment: @syb0rg That's a fair point, it depends on the application. If you need the attention of the user, center of the screen is not ally best (if its not maximised) - IMHO

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Swap the `pack` and `setResizable` calls, so that `pack` is the second call.

In the following example, it will write `200x200` on the panel, if you swap the calls it will write `210x210`

This is a known "issue"

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestResizeFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestResizeFrame();
    }

    public TestResizeFrame() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                // Will appear as 200x200, swap them and it will appear as 210x210
                frame.setResizable(false);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g); 
            FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
            g.drawString(getWidth() + "x" + getHeight(), 0, fm.getAscent());
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, now at least the panel is correctly sized. The problem is the frame and the canvas are still too large. Especially a problem since I am drawing on the buffer of the canvas, technically I could code it so I won't ever draw outside of the visible panel but I would love to know why this happens.

Comment: The size of the frame will be the preferred size of the content pane PLUS the window border. You can not, safely calculate this, so I'd ignore it and worry about, focus on getting the game area the size you want it.