# JFrame.setResizable(false); not working

Tags: java, window, jframe, jpanel, resizable

I'm working on an online mode for a new game and in order to prevent cheating I need fix window sizes (and both players need a window with the same sizes).

I used 'jframe.setResizable(false);' but it seems to be "glitchy".

When I click the window and move it away from the border of the screen, Windows does minimize it.

Here's a video about it:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AQ7OHJOuLSk&feature=youtu.be

I've tried following code in order to fix it:

```
  Dimension d = new Dimension(width, height);
    panel.getJFrame().setMaximumSize(d);
    panel.getJFrame().setMinimumSize(d);
    panel.setMaximumSize(d);
    panel.setMinimumSize(d);
```

and I created a Component Listener:

```
    if (max_height!=-1){
        if (e.getComponent().getSize().getHeight()>max_height){
            e.getComponent().setSize((int) e.getComponent().getSize().getWidth(),max_height);
        }
    }
    if (max_width!=-1){
        if (e.getComponent().getSize().getHeight()>max_width){
            e.getComponent().setSize(max_width,(int) e.getComponent().getSize().getHeight());
        }
```

and I tried to work with Layouts but nothing worked.

What I need now is either the possibility to prevent that minimize "glitch" (If it is a glitch) or a way to make the JPanel not resizable. Like when the size of the JFrame window is changed, the JPanel always stays the same. It's neither streched nor minimized.

Help is much appreciated :)

Sincerely Felix

Comment: Start by providing size hints for your main pane (not the frame) by overriding getPreferred/Minimum/MaximumSize. Set the main layout on the frame to something like GridBagLayout, use JFrame#pack to set the frame size

Comment: Also, beware, that setResizable(false) can change the frame size, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15560527/frame-and-canvas-grow-larger-than-specified/15560624#15560624) for details

Comment: Post your `SSCCE` that demonstrates a problem, not a video.

Answer (score 2):

So far the best patch for this annoying issue is the following. Doesn't matter where you call the `setResizable(false)` method. Just add this piece of code after you `setVisible(true)`.

```
private void sizeBugPatch() {
    while (frame.getWidth() > yourWidth) {
        frame.pack();
    }
}
```

Where `yourWidth` is the *width* you've set in any of the possible ways, either manually or by overriding `setPreferredSize` methods. The explanation is quite easy, `frame.pack()` seems to reset `frame.setResizable(boolean b)` somehow. You could use an `if` instead of the `while` loop but I prefer `while` to exclude the case the window would still be extra-sized even after a second `pack()`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you initialize the variable `jframe` or are you calling the general Class?

Because if you do it like this:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setResizable(false);
```

It works fine for me...