# Weird rendering result when JFrame is set as not resizable, but not when it is resizable

Tags: java, rendering

I'm creating a game and I have a JFrame with a custom Canvas in it. **The weird thing is** that when I set the JFrame to *BE RESIZABLE*, the rendering result looks like this:

[image: The result when the JFrame is set to BE resizable]

But when I set the JFrame to *NOT BE RESIZABLE*, the result looks like this:

[image: The result when the JFrame is set to NOT BE resizable]

The method which adds the texture's pixel array to the BufferedImage's pixel array looks like this:

```
// DRAW A TEXTURE ON THE CANVAS
public void drawTexture(Texture texture, Vector2i location) {
    // Store the current texture coordinates
    int tx = 0, ty = 0;
    // Scroll through each pixel on the screen horizontally (begin at the X coordinate specified by the 'location')
    for(int x = location.x; (x < getWidth() && x < location.x + texture.getWidth()); x++) {
        // Scroll through each pixel on the screen vertically (begin at the Y coordinate specified by the 'location')
        for(int y = location.y; (y < getHeight() && y < location.y + texture.getHeight()); y++) {
            // Set each pixel to the color of the corresponding pixel on the Texture
            pixels[x + y * getWidth()] = texture.getPixels()[tx + ty * texture.getWidth()];
            // Add one to the texture Y coordinate
            ty++;
        }
        // Reset the ty variable
        ty = 0;
        // Add one to the texture X coordinate
        tx++;
    }
}
```

And the `BufferedImage` is drawn inside of a loop in the run method of my custom canvas.
The custom canvas class (extends `Canvas` offcourse) implements `Runnable`, and it also contains an own `Thread` for rendering.

I wonder if anyone know why this happens, and maybe how to fix it, because I can't figure it out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the working answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15560527/frame-and-canvas-grow-larger-than-specified), because I found out that the Canvas was bigger than what I had set it to, so I googled for that, and that answer fixed both problems.

*Quote from the answer to [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15560527/frame-and-canvas-grow-larger-than-specified):*

> Swap the `pack` and `setResizable` calls, so that `pack` is the second call.

*and*

> This is a known "issue"

*Question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15560527/frame-and-canvas-grow-larger-than-specified).*