# Frame and Canvas created in cycle grow larger than specified when setResizeable(false)

Tags: java, swing

I've just read this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/15560624/3211987 but if I add for cycle, size of the first JFrame is ok, but the others are 10 pixels larger. Is this a feature? Or why is this happening?

Only if frame.pack() is called twice, the final size is correct.

```
public class TestResizableFrame {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 25; ++i)
          new TestResizableFrame();
     }

     public TestResizableFrame() {
          EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new FixedPane());
                frame.setResizable(false);
                frame.pack(); // if called twice, the size is correct
                // frame.pack(); // uncomment to get correct size 
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class FixedPane extends JPanel {

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Dimension size = getSize();
            String text = size.width + "x" + size.height;
            FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
            int x = (getWidth()- fm.stringWidth(text)) / 2;
            int y = ((getHeight() - fm.getHeight()) / 2) + fm.getAscent();
            g.drawString(text, x, y);
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.drawRect(0, 0, 199, 199);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I only see one call to `pack`?

Comment: See edit, I added the second call.

Comment: As you noticed, the insets of the frame on some OSs change by 10px for some reason (maybe a bug for the correspoding OSs if the visible border doesn't change the size). Another solution would be to just call `setResizable()` after `add()`

Comment: `setResizeable()` is already called after `add()` :) So I don't think it is a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a really interesting problem that bothered me a lot. From doing some try and error I found a solution that seems reliable for me.
You have to call `setVisible` AFTER `setResizable` and BEFORE `pack`

```
frame.add(new FixedPane());
frame.setResizable(false);
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.pack();
```

The question stays why does this have to be this way. There is nothing documented about the order of these calls.

Comment: Also `frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);` have to be before `setVisible`. If it is after windows are created in the upper left corner and then jump to the middle of the screen.